# Order mysql fetched data by the same content of a field

Tags: php, mysql

i have a database with: city / age
for example:
Chicago 24
York 33
Chicago 54
London 12
York 21
London 1

How can i oreder thing like this?
Chicago 24
Chicago 54
York 33
York 21
London 1
London 12

Basically order them by the name of the town. I use this for a php display records script.

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM towns WHERE .........");
```

Comment: I dont see the patter in that order!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the order of the results you use `ORDER BY`, not `WHERE`.

```
SELECT city, age
FROM towns
ORDER BY city
```

If you want the cities in the order in your example then use [`FIELD`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

```
SELECT city, age
FROM towns
ORDER BY FIELD(city, 'Chicago', 'York', 'London')
```

Comment: Hmm is the syntax ok? i want to order by Field, not working, mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT city, age FROM towns ORDER BY city DESC, age;
```

That will order by `city DESC` first and then `age [ASC]` second... which is what I believe you require.